# Is there a Material Design spec for the ShowCase view?

Tags: android, material-design

I want to implement Material Design on my app and I need a showcase view to introduce some of its parts. Now I've noticed that there isn't a spec for the said view on the Material Design website. I also can't find any developer who created his custom 'materialized' Showcase view.

Do you guys know a webpage showing me how to implement Material design on this view?

Comment: have you tried to Google it?? here is docs : http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html or add image or link to show us your design

Comment: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Comment: @Rajan Not materialized. But thanks.

Comment: I am also trying to find something like this. I implemented amlcurran/ShowcaseView, but it is a bit dated. Will continue looking for something better

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is not updated yet but here is what I did on my app:

```
<!-- *** SHOWCASE *** -->
<style name="CustomShowcaseMaterial" parent="ShowcaseView">
    <item name="sv_backgroundColor">?mainColor</item>
    <item name="sv_showcaseColor">?accentColor</item>
    <item name="sv_buttonText">@string/ok</item>
    <item name="sv_titleTextAppearance">@style/CustomTitleMaterial</item>
    <item name="sv_detailTextAppearance">@style/CustomTextMaterial</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTitleMaterial" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTextMaterial" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Then you need to set `withMaterialShowCase()` and apply the style created above on the `ShowcaseView` builder, for example:

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTarget(target)
                .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseMaterial)
                .setContentTitle(R.string.showcase_title)
                .setContentText(R.string.showcase_message)
                .hideOnTouchOutside()
                .withMaterialShowcase()
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit old question, but the needed Material Design specs are called [Feature-Discovery](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/growth-communications/feature-discovery.html)

And there is a nice library called [TapTargetView](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView), which implements those guidelines